# java, springboot. String value in json numeric type cannot be saved ORACLE

Tags: java, json, spring, database, oracle

I am in the process of merging data in json format into oracle database.
But only these guys can't insert the value. What's the problem?

Is the query written in xml the problem?

**Controller**

*GRADE_JSON_PATH is the name of the variable that loads the json file below.*

```
@PostMapping("/grade")
    public ResponseEntity<Void> mergeCommonCodeGrade() {
        ObjectMapper obj = new ObjectMapper();

        InputStream gradeJsonInput = TypeReference.class.getResourceAsStream(GRADE_JSON_PATH);

        try {
            CommonCodeDTO[] commonCodeDTO = obj.readValue(gradeJsonInput, CommonCodeDTO[].class);

            mapper.innoMergeIntoCommonCodeGrade(commonCodeDTO);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.getMessage();
        }

        return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT);
    }
```

**GRADE_JSON_PATH**

*X1 is stored in DB, but 13 and 15 are not.*

```
[
  {
    "code" : "X1",
    "codeName" : "GOOD"
  },
  {
    "code" : "13",
    "codeName" : "MB5"
  },
  {
    "code" : "15",
    "codeName" : "SAN"
  }
]
```

**XML**

```
<update id="innoMergeIntoCommonCodeGrade" parameterType="java.util.List">
        MERGE INTO inno.B_COMMON_CODE A1
        USING (
        <foreach collection="commonCodeDTO" item="item" index="index" separator="UNION" open="" close="">
            SELECT
            'GRADE' AS MASTER_CODE
            , #{item.code} AS CODE
            , #{item.codeName} AS CODE_NAME
            , 'Y' AS STATUS
            , 'admin' AS REG_ID
            , TO_CHAR(SYSDATE,'YYYYMMDD') AS REG_DATE
            , TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'HH24MISS') AS REG_TIME
            , 'admin' AS MOD_ID
            , TO_CHAR(SYSDATE,'YYYYMMDD') AS MOD_DATE
            , TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'HH24MISS') AS MOD_TIME
            FROM DUAL
        </foreach>
        ) T1
        ON (A1.CODE = T1.CODE)
        WHEN MATCHED THEN
        UPDATE SET
        A1.CODE_NAME = T1.CODE_NAME,
        A1.MOD_ID = T1.MOD_ID,
        A1.MOD_DATE = T1.MOD_DATE,
        A1.MOD_TIME = T1.MOD_TIME
        WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
        INSERT (
          A1.MASTER_CODE
        , A1.CODE
        , A1.CODE_NAME
        , A1.STATUS
        , A1.REG_ID
        , A1.REG_DATE
        , A1.REG_TIME
        , A1.MOD_ID
        , A1.MOD_DATE
        , A1.MOD_TIME
        )
        VALUES (
          T1.MASTER_CODE
        , T1.CODE
        , T1.CODE_NAME
        , T1.STATUS
        , T1.REG_ID
        , T1.REG_DATE
        , T1.REG_TIME
        , T1.MOD_ID
        , T1.MOD_DATE
        , T1.MOD_TIME
        )
    </update>
```

Comment: Is your <foreach> loop actually doing anything? I'm not sure you can embed that in a `USING()` clause. Also, why store date information as text? This is pretty much always a bad idea: it takes more space and makes interval calculations much, much harder (basically impossible, as text, without another conversion). The standard approach would be to store it as a single `date` field and convert to text as appropriate for individual needs when the information is retrieved.

Comment: inside the tag, It is mapping the values ​​read into the json file. Date information is just an example .lol. So can you answer my question?